# Expectation under conditional distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am trying to understand the following equivalence:

\begin{array}{c}{\mathbb{E}_{p(x, y)}\left[\log \frac{q(x | y)}{p(x)} \frac{p(x | y)}{q(x | y)}\right] =\mathbb{E}_{p(x, y)}\left[\log \frac{q(x | y)}{p(x)}\right]+\mathbb{E}_{p(y)}\left[D_{K L}(p(x | y) \| q(x | y))\right]}\end{array}

which is used in [1] at eq. 2.
The first term is clear to me. However I don't understand completely how the second term is calculated.
As far as I understand it is based on the following:

$
\mathbb{E}_{p(x,y)}\left[\log \frac{p(x | y)}{q(x | y)}\right] = \mathbb{E}_{p(y)}\left[D_{K L}(p(x | y) \| q(x | y))\right]
$

Apparently we have;

$D_{K L}(p(x | y) \| q(x | y)) = \mathbb{E}_{p(x | y)}\left[\log \frac{p(x | y)}{q(x | y)}\right]$

So to my understanding this implies the following:

$
\mathbb{E}_{p(x,y)}\left[\log \frac{p(x | y)}{q(x | y)}\right] = 
\mathbb{E}_{p(y)}\left[ \mathbb{E}_{p(x | y)}\left[\log \frac{p(x | y)}{q(x | y)}\right]\right]
$

Unfortunately It is not clear to me how respectively why $\mathbb{E}_{p(x,y)}$ can be decomposed into this nested expectations under the marginal $p(y)$ and the conditional $p(x|y)$.
I think I am clearly missing a very simple point here.

[1] https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.06922.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation): Quite generally,

$$
\mathbb E_{p(x,y)}[Z]=\mathbb E_{p(y)}\left[\mathbb E_{p(x\mid y)}[Z]\right]\;.
$$

That is, you can first form the expectation as if you knew $Y$, and then form the expectation of the result using the marginal distribution of $Y$. In the discrete case, this is just

$$
\sum_{x,y}p(x,y)Z(x,y)=\sum_y\left(\sum_\xi p(\xi,y)\right)\sum_x\frac{p(x,y)}{\sum_\xi p(\xi,y)}Z(x,y)\;.
$$